# Proving that product of two quotients = a certain quotient group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Question

I am producing certain given conditions from a paper and a certain fact(stated in the paper) that I need to prove using those conditions. I am converting this problem into a general group theory problem and providing my proof. I would like to get this proof verified as I believe there could be unseen errors.

Let $G_1, G_2$ be normal sub groups of a group $G$ such that $N_1
\trianglelefteq G_1$, $N_2 \trianglelefteq G_2$ and
$N \trianglelefteq G$. Also, $N_1, N_2 \leq N$. Also, $(G_1/N_1)$ and $(G_2/N_2)$ are sub groups of $(G/N)$.
I have the following information at hand.

1)Any element w in $G$ is congruent modulo N (with symbol
$\sim$) to $\alpha\beta$ where $\alpha$ $\in$ $G_1$ and $\beta$ $\in$ $G_2$.
i.e., $w \sim \alpha\beta$ means $wN = \alpha\beta N$

2) G/N is abelian.
Need to prove: $G/N$ = $(G_1/N_1)(G_2/N_2)$

Proof

For $w \in G$,
$wN$ = $\alpha \beta N$ = $\alpha N \beta N$ =
$\alpha(\gamma_aN)\beta(\gamma_bN)$ where $\gamma_a \in N_1$ and $\gamma_b \in N_2$ (Note that $N_1, N_2 \leq N$). 
 = $\alpha\gamma_a(\beta N)(\gamma_bN)$ as $N \trianglelefteq G$.

Similarly, as $N\gamma_b$ = $\gamma_b N$, so, for any $wg \in wN$, $wg = \alpha\gamma_a\beta\gamma_b\gamma$ for some $\gamma \in N$. 
$\Rightarrow$ $w(g\gamma^{-1}) = \alpha\gamma_a\beta\gamma_b$.

Note that $g\gamma^{-1} \in N$ corresponds to an arbitrary element in $N$.
Thus, any element in $wN$ can be written as $\alpha$ times(an element in $N_1$)times $\beta$ times(an element in $N_2$). $\Rightarrow$ $wN \in \alpha N_1\beta N_2$. Thus, $G/N \subseteq (G_1/N_1)(G_2/N_2)$. Note that $(G_1/N_1)(G_2/N_2)$ is a group as G/N is abelian and its sub groups are normal to it.

To prove the other way around, since, $G_1/N_1$, $G_2/N_2 \trianglelefteq G/N$,

$(G_1/N_1)(G_2/N_2) \leq$ (more accurately, $\trianglelefteq)$ $G/N$. So, $(G_1/N_1)(G_2/N_2) = G/N$.
Is this proof acceptable?

Comment: The product of two subgroups of a given group is defined, but there is no definition of the product of two unrelated groups. So I am afraid that the statement $G/N = (G_1/N_1)(G_2/N_2)$ that you want to prove does not even make sense.

Comment: I am editing the question. What you said is true. 
In this case, (G1/N1) and (G2/N2) are sub groups of (G/N) in the sense that there exists an injective homomorphism from either quotient groups to (G/N).

Comment: I have assumed that they are sub groups in my proof, however missed to mention it in the question. Is the proof correct?

Comment: If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are proper subgroups of $N$, then it is not true that $G/N_1$ and $G/N_2$ are subgroups of $G/N$. You cannot assume something that is not true!

Comment: Sir, I am terribly sorry for not stating my problem correctly earlier. After you pointed out this error, I added this assumption into my problem. My claim would work only if, as you pointed out, if this assumption is added. I am not twisting the problem for the answer's case, but in a specific case in a paper that I am reading, it so happens that the groups corresponding to G_i/N_i in my paper are in fact sub groups of G/N which I had not mentioned as a condition in my problem(My mistake).

Comment: Please note that I am assuming G_i/N_i-s as sub-groups of G/N. Not only just N_1, N_2 as sub groups of N.

Comment: As I said before, you cannot assume what is not true. Your statement "Also $G/N_1$, $G/N_2$ are subgroups of $G/N$" is simply false unless $N=N_1=N_2$.

Comment: Kindly refer to the Lemma on page 590 [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-04/S0002-9939-1952-0049191-5/S0002-9939-1952-0049191-5.pdf). On page 592, it is proved that H(G) = i^* H(A) j^* H(B).